# Using git submodules with python

Tags: python, git, setuptools

I've read a lot of blog posts and questions on this site about the usage of git submodules and still have no idea how to better use them with python.

I mean, what is the easier way to manage dependencies if I have such a package:

```
├── mypkg
│   └── __init__.py
├── setup.py
└── submodules
    ├── subm1
    └── subm2
```

Then, what if I need to use "mypkg" as a submodule for "top_level_pkg":

```
├── setup.py
├── submodules
│   └── mypkg
└── top_level_package
    └── __init__.py
```

, I want to run `pip install .` and have all resolved correctly (have each submodule installed to the VENV in correct order).

What I've tried:

- Install each submodule using "pip" running in a subprocess. But it seems to be a hacky way and hard to manage ([Unexpected installation of GIT submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64986548/unexpected-installation-of-git-submodule))
- Use "install_requires" with "setuptools.find_packages()" but without success
- Use requirements.txt file for each submodule, but I can't find a way how to automate it so "pip" could automatically install all requirements for all submodules.

Ideally, I imagine a separate setup.py file for each submodule with `install_requires=['submodules/subm1', 'submodules/submn']`, but setuptools does not support it.

Comment: Do the submodules have their own `setup.py` or not? In other words are they projects that are _pip_ installable independently?

Comment: @sinoroc, yes, exactly.

Comment: Have you tried `install_requires=['subm1 @ submodules/subm1', '...']`?

Comment: Otherwise you might not need submodules at all: `install_requires=['subm1 @ git+https://repo.dev/subm1.git', '...']`.

Comment: @sinoroc, No, i have not even noticed such syntax in the documentation. Thank you, I'll try it.

Comment: @sinoroc, It seems to be incorrect syntax because I get: "'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Invalid URL: submodules/subm1"

Comment: Ah yes, I should have linked the specification:https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references -- you need an absolute path, something like `subm1 @ file:///path/to/subm1`. So it might not work for your use case. Try the git variant instead. You would not need to worry about git submodules then.

Comment: It seems like the final answer is that there's no PORTABLE way to construct a python project with git submodules and have setuptools install the git submodule code before the parent, do I have that right? Using an absolute path in a file:// URL in setup.py fails on Jenkins CI build servers, just to name one glaring problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying it's impossible, but very hard and very tricky. A safer way is to turn each submodule into an installable Python module (with it's own `setup.py`) and install the submodules from Git.

This link describes how to install packages from Git with `setup.py`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32689886/2952185

Comment: It turned out to be not very hard and not very tricky, at least if I understood the OP's question correctly, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully to **Gijs Wobben** and **sinoroc** I came up with solution that works for my case:

```
install_requires=['subm1 @ file://localhost/<CURENT_DIR>/path/to/subm1']
```

Comment: An absolute path works but is hopelessly unportable. Like @garrywreck I want to use a relative path for portability but just get the error `'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers`

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to install a Python package from a git submodule together with a main package. These are proprietary and are never published to PyPI.  And both pip and tox seem to work just fine.

To set the context, I have a git repo with a single Python package and a single git submodule; the git submodule also contains a single Python package. I think this structure is as generic and simple as it can possibly be, here's a visualization:

```
main-git-repo-name
├── mainpkg
│   └── __init__.py
├── setup.py
├── tests
└── util-git-repo-name (this is a git submodule)
    ├── setup.py
    ├── test
    └── utilpkg
        └── __init__.py
```

I wanted to have pip install everything in a single invocation, and the utilpkg should be usable in mainpkg via just `import utilpkg` (not nested oddly).

The answer for me was all in `setup.py`:

First, specify the packages to install and their locations:

```
packages=find_packages(exclude=["tests"])
       + find_packages(where="util-git-repo-name/utilpkg", exclude=["test"]),
package_dir={
    "mainpkg": "mainpkg",
    "utilpkg": "util-git-repo-name/utilpkg"
},
```

Second, copy all the `install_requires` items from the git submodule package's `setup.py` file into the top level. In my case the utility package is an API client generated by swagger-codegen, so I had to add:

```
install_requires=[
    "urllib3 >= 1.15", "six >= 1.10", "certifi", "python-dateutil",
    ...],
```

Anyhow, when running `pip3 install .` this config results in exactly what I want in the site-packages area: a directory mainpkg/ and a directory utilpkg/

HTH